# Ruby on Rails - get one column for every record of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have a model "User" with 'email', 'name', and 'password'.

How can I get all emails? `User.all` gives the entire row for every record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
User.pluck(:email)
```

Documentation: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `select` method from ActiveRecord: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Answer (score 0):

Model.pluck(attribute) will return an array of that attribute for instance, but by separating it into an array you lose the association with the instance. So, depending on what you need to do, the more verbose Model.all.each {|item| #some code eg: item.email } will give you the attribute but still allow you to call back to the Model instance if needed.